# VB.NET WPF 2 TreeViews same ItemsSource

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, xaml, treeview

currently I am trying to give to TreeViews the same TreeViewItem.

But its only visible in one of them.

I am not sure why...

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TreeView x:Name="t1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="300" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="238"/>
        <TreeView x:Name="t2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="300" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="239" Grid.Column="1"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.vb:

```
Class MainWindow

    Private root As TreeViewItem

    Public Sub New()

        ' Dieser Aufruf ist für den Designer erforderlich.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Fügen Sie Initialisierungen nach dem InitializeComponent()-Aufruf hinzu.
        root = New TreeViewItem()
        Dim obj1 As TreeViewItem = New TreeViewItem()
        Dim obj2 As TreeViewItem = New TreeViewItem()

        root.Header = "TEST"
        obj1.Header = "obj1"
        obj2.Header = "obj2"

        root.ItemsSource = {obj1, obj2}

        t1.ItemsSource = {root}
        t2.ItemsSource = {root}
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the `TreeViewItem`s are already the visual objects the `TreeView` uses. If you use any other custom object and format them to what you want to display in the `ItemTemplate` of the `TreeView` you will be able to use the same objects.

But you can't do that with `TreeViewItem`s.